# How to make a LEFT JOIN on a one-sided relation between two tables in HQL?

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, left-join, hql

The title is explicit, so here is the detail : I have two tables, A and B. **B has a reference to A but the other way around is not true**. In SQL it does not really change anything, but in HQL I can not figure out how to do :

> A **LEFT JOIN** B **ON** *condition*

I tried :

> A a **LEFT JOIN** B b **JOIN** b.A ba **WITH** a.id = ba.id

*--> QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!*

> A a **LEFT JOIN** B b **WITH** a.id = b.A.id

*--> QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!*

I don't get the path exception as I always give an alias. I guess I'm doing something that doesn't make sense, or most probably it is because I need to do **A a LEFT JOIN a.B**, but I can't...(I tried **B b RIGHT JOIN b.A**. It works but of course the result is not what I need)

I also tried without the WITH clause because the condition is on the **FK**, but no more sucess.

If you have any ideas, please, I'm listening !

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to do such ad hoc joins you need at least Hibernate 5.1. JPA still doesn't support such kind of things.

Try to use this query

```
class A {

  @Id
  private Long pid;

}

class B {

  @Id
  private Long pid;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn
  private A refToA; 

}

from A a left join B b on a.pid = b.refToA.pid
```

Comment: Thank, you, But how is it different from my second example I tried ? My Hibernate version is 3.2.2

Comment: @Flyout You can't do this `A a LEFT JOIN B b` using Hibernate 3. You need to have a reference to `B` in `A`.

Comment: Okay that's what I guessed but I did not know it was because of the version. Thank you I wrill try to find an other solution.

Comment: @Flyout You can try to use a cartesian product. But It will be an inner join. You need to use the `union` to simulate the `left outer join`. But I don't know can it be used with HQL.

Comment: Yes I was wondering how to do a left outer join to add the result to the inner join ! Thanks I did not know about the union I will look if it is possible.

Comment: @Flyout It will be interesting, if you report about your results.

Comment: I think there is no way to do it in HQL with this version (I didn't find any solution to do a union). I just went with SQL instead. Sad.

Comment: @Flyout Thank you :)